# Store JSON file contents on load

Tags: angularjs

Right now, I have a factory which loads a JSON file.

```
angular.module("app").factory("RolesFactory", ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    var d = $q.defer();
    $http.get('events.json').success(function(data) {
        d.resolve(data);
    }); 
    return d.promise;
}]);
```

And then I call this factory when I need the contents of events.json with this controller:

```
App.controller('rolesCtrl', ['$scope', 'RolesFactory', function($scope, RolesFactory) {
    RolesFactory.then(function(roleData){
        $scope.roles = roleData.roles;
    });
}]);
```

All good, but whenever I need to use this data. Isn't it refetching the contents of events.json? Meaning: is Angular reloading the file over and over again? I was hoping to load the file once and call it by a global variable or something.

When my app loads initially, I want it to load and store the contens of events.json -- and then I'd like my app to be able to use this data whenever/wherever.

Is this possible?

Comment: *"Isn't it refetching the contents of events.json?"* did you open the console to see for yourself?

Comment: Well yeah, but is it reloading the file twice if I call the factory twice?

Comment: ... you would be able to see it twice in your network console if it was. My point is asking that question is pointless, because you can try it and see the result immediately.

Comment: I didn't think to check the network tab as I wasn't even sure what to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As AngularJS is a stateless framework, you have only a few options here, all of which are some kind of client-side caching:

1. Use `localStorage` to store your data. Once the data is fetched, you can just save it to `localStorage` using `localStorage.setItem` after Stringifying the JSON. You'll need to re-parse the JSON the next time you use it though, so if this is a giant JSON, this is not the best idea
2. Use `sessionStorage` to store your data. This is exactly the same as #1, but you will lose data upon termination of session,i.e. closing your browser.
3. Trust the JSON to be cached in your browser. This is most likely the case. Static assets are by default cached by most modern browsers. So, the second time your factory requests the JSON, the resource isn't actually fetched from the server. It is merely pulled from the browser's cache.

**NOTE:** The way to check this is to see what the HTTP status code for your resource is, in Chrome's Developer Tools Network tab. If the status says `304` that means it has been pulled from cache.

[image]

Comment: Re 3: Thank you for the explanation. I was assuming that every time I tried to use the factory, it was actually _reloading_ the json file.

Comment: If the JSON was served by an API end point, that might have been the case. But as long as this is a static JSON file, the browser will cache the file after first load.
If my answer has helped you, please mark it as correct. Happy coding!